# How to read “\n” text in file as a newline?

Tags: java, text, text-files, newline

My text file contains this 1 line

`This line is used for testing.\nTesting testing testing.`

And this is how I read that line in Java

```
import java.util.List;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.io.IOException;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> list = null;
      try {
            list = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("path to txt file"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String[] Array = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
  }
}
```

And when I print it out with System.out.print(Array[0]); I get this as a result: `This line is used for testing.\nTesting testing testing.`

I want the result to be like this:

`This line is used for testing.`

`Testing testing testing.`

Comment: What is your operating system?

Comment: Windows 10 Pro on version 2004

Comment: Would you please edit the code to be an [mre]. I should be able to copy from your question, paste it into my IDE, adjust for file location, and compile. You nee a main() and the necessary imports.

Comment: Edited it to be as a reproducible example

Comment: What editor did you use to make the test file? I'm finding it difficult (under windows) to put just a \n rather than a \n\r.

Comment: IDE is IntelliJ IDEA, txt file is notepad

Comment: How did you insert the \n?

Comment: Manually inside the txt file

Comment: In other words, this is just a "\" followed by an "n". Sorry, I was thinking that the file had a newline inserted in it. Your file just has two characters without any special meaning.

Answer (score 1):

If you want such behavior, the best way is to implement this in your code:

```
list = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(""))
                    .stream()
                    .flatMap(line -> Arrays.stream(line.split("\\\\n")))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This read the files, like you did, plus it interprets the `\n` to give you new Lines every time.

That's the only way I've found

Comment: Don't you mean `split("\\\\n")`?

Comment: why `\\\\n` not `\\n`?

Answer (score 0):

Typing `\n` in a text file doesn't give you a newline, it gives you the individual characters `\` and `n`. If you want to add a newline and have your program print out the text with that newline, you'll have to actually insert a newline (ie. press enter).

If you want to make your program be able to understand escaped characters (process `\n` as a newline), you'd have to add that logic yourself. The simplest way would be to iterate over each character and if a character is `\`, process according to the next character. In your case, once you see `\` followed by `n`, delete those two characters and insert a newline in their place.

Comment: This is the correct answer.  When we embed "\n" in a String in our code, it is an escape sequence which represents a newline character, which is not otherwise printable in a form we can readily interpret.